# I'd like to clarify if it's possible to increase an amount of reviews from 5 per location to all it has

Tags: google-places-api, review

It's necessary to show all the reviews of almost 60 venues via Maps. The amount of reviews may vary from 1 to 10 (supposably) depanding on the location. According to Google Places API it's only possible to return only 5 reviews via JSON. So i'd like to clarify if there's any solution exists to return all the reviews which these venues have?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently supported by the Google Maps Platform -- **Places API**.

More people asked for this so there is a feature request for this: Places API: Response to Include More Than 5 Reviews ─ I'd recommend you to comment your use-case in there and "star" it to receive updates:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825957

This Issue Tracker entry is the authoritative source for public information regarding this issue, and all publicly-relevant updates will be posted there. Starring the issue also provides Google with valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to customers, and increases the issue's priority with the product engineering team.